# Why is nullable int id parameter always null in ASP.NET Core web app?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application with the following controller method that isn't working as expected:

```
[Route("Edit/{id:int?}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id){....}
```

Calling this endpoint with a url like `controllername/Edit/1` or `controllername/Edit?id=1` both result in the `id` being null. If I change it to be an `int` instead of an `int?`, it works fine.

What's wrong with that method signature and route?

This route configuration is in my `Program.cs` file.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's [Route("sales/pipeline")], so the actual url being called is `/sales/pipeline/edit/1` or `/sales/pipeline/edit?id=1`

Answer (score 0):

You have put the `?` in the wrong place in your route constraint.  `int?` is not a [supported constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

If you want to mark the parameter as optional for purposes of routing, use `id?:int`

```
[Route("Edit/{id?:int}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id){....}
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error - The route parameter name 'id?' is invalid. Route parameter names must be non-empty and cannot contain these characters: '{', '}', '/'. The '?' character marks a parameter as optional, and can occur only at the end of the parameter.